# Extracting RAR archive into multiple directories on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, rar

On a Windows box, I need to extract a RAR archive so that individual files in it go into specific directories. I can provide, say, a text file that lists each file and the target directory for it? Then I need help creating a batch file that will actually extract these files into their target locations.

E.g. 
RAR archive `x.rar` contains

```
a.a
b.b
c.c
```

Text file `x.txt` says

```
a.a   C:\foo
b.b   C:\bar
c.c   C:\foo
```

Result of running batch file on `x.rar` and `x.txt` should be:

- in `C:\foo` we have `a.a` and `c.c`
- in `C:\bar` we have `b.b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `rar` a list of file names to extract with `-n@<listfile>`. So if you create a single file for each directory you want to extract to this should be a viable option. However, the file you describe to have doesn't quite match the format; you'd need to group it by target directory (much more fun in PowerShell by the way).

However, if the archive you're extracting is a solid archive this will take far longer since you essentially have to decompress *the whole archive* over and over again.

The best and probably easiest method would then probably to extract the archive once and *then* sort all files in their respective directories.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it's easiest to just extract it and move the files in a batch file instead.